# it seems like my JS code is skipping my for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Like the title says, it seems like my for loop is being skipped. I'm trying to make a Logisim compatible hex file so I don't have to hand program instruction's for the CPU I'm designing

Here is said for loop:

```js
var head = "v3.0 hex words addressed\n"
var data = "0x0000: "
for(i = 0; i > 0x3ff7; i++) {
    if (i % 8 == 0) {
        data = "0x" + i.toString(16).padStart(4, "0") + ":" + data + "\n"
    } else {
        if(i>miCode.length) {
            nop.forEach((e, i) => {
                data = data + e.toString(16).padStart(4, "0") + " "
            })
        } else {
            data = data + " " + miCode[i]
        }
    }
}
console.log(head + data);
console.log(miCode)
```

This is what I get in return:

```
v3.0 hex words addressed
0x0000:
[
   262656,  1114368,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0,
        0,   262656, 1114368,  393216, 1048578,        0,       0,
        0,        0,  262656, 1114368,  393216,  1048584,       0,
        0,        0,       0,  262656, 1114368,   393216, 1048608,
        0,        0,       0,       0,  262656,  1114368,  393216,
   524292,        0,       0,       0,       0,   262656, 1114368,
   393216,   524304,       0,       0,       0,        0,  262656,
  1114368,   393216,  524352,       0,       0,        0,       0,
   262656,  1114368,  131074,       0,       0,        0,       0,
        0,   262656, 1114368,  131080,       0,        0,       0,
        0,        0,  262656, 1114368,  131104,        0,       0,
        0,        0,       0,  262656, 1114368, 16908288,       0,
        0,        0,       0,       0,  262656,  1114368,  393216,
  1048608, 33554432, 8388672,       0,       0,   262656, 1114368,
  4194336,  8402944,
  ... 337 more items
]
```

Comment: if i starts at zero,it's NEVER greater than a positive number

Comment: `i > 0x3ff7` means: keep looping as long as `i` is greater than `0x3ff7`. Is that the case when `i` is `0` at the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace > with < in the loop condition.  Yours is testing false because it only runs if i (initialized to 0) is greater than 0x3ff7 (16375), which it is not.

Answer (score 1):

change `i < 0x3ff7` and your loops should work.